# If a computer gets infected with malware, can the host firewall block the malware from communicating back to its controller on the internet?

Tags: malware, http, firewalls, tunneling

I'm trying to figure out how secure a host firewall is, hence the question in the title.
I read that many firewalls allow outbound connections to port 80 to allow browsing, would that be enough for the malware to communicate to the controller?
would it be possible with tunneling? This would allow me to carry with HTTP a second protocol that used alone would be disallowed by firewall policy.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the firewall and on the malware.

If the malware is able to subvert the firewall or disable it, meaning that it also target the firewall itself, then it can do whatever it pleases.

If the malware does not attack the firewall, too, then it also depends on the standalone firewall itself, along with the privilege of execution of the malware.
E.g., a standalone firewall could allow HTTP or HTTPS access on ports 80 and 443, respectively, only for applications that are reputable browser. But, this level of granularity is not usually present on consumer firewalls. Firewalls likely block many other ports by default, but usually not 80 and 443. Hence, likely the consumer firewall will not block malware communicating on 80 or 443.

But, most consumer firewall solutions are not standalone, but come as a full suite of anti-malware solutions, that also include application control. For example, the anti-malware solution I use will not allow internet access for untrusted applications and an application that is not known to be a browser.

Answer (score -2):

No, a firewall won't block the malware from communicating with the controller. There are too many ways to exfiltrate data, and blocking every single one is not possible without blocking almost every legitimate connection too.

Some people advise about using whitelisting to allow communication only with pre-defined addresses or domains, but that would be very cumbersome to maintain, while still allowing creative malware creators to use legitimate sites to communicate with the controllers ([Domain Fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_fronting), [posting encoded comments](https://www.businessinsider.com/russian-hackers-turla-communicate-malware-britney-spears-instagram-comment-2017-6) on social media, [DNS tunneling](https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/cyberpedia/what-is-dns-tunneling)).

Comment: Technically, a firewall *can*, but most measures can be defeated by simply making the traffic look legitimate.

Comment: I would go even further. yes you can controle what data leaves your node / machine (especially if you controle the outgoing connections of your ISP link)… however almost nobody sets there system up like that since you need to adjust config for every new IP you connect with….